# PostgreSQL timestamp select

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Posture and I got error message "invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone" when using the following select code:

```
SELECT * FROM public."table1" WHERE 'registrationTimestamp' BETWEEN 
to_timestamp('22-10-2013 00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
AND to_timestamp('22-10-2013 23:59', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')**
```

While `registrationTimestamp` timestamp format is like following:

```
6/26/2012  6:43:10 PM
```

Comment: if `registrationTimestamp` is a column, it does not have a format. Datatypes don't have formats in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is wrong using of apostrophes

Should be

```
SELECT * FROM public."table1" 
 WHERE "registrationTimestamp" BETWEEN 
            to_timestamp('22-10-2013 00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
        AND to_timestamp('22-10-2013 23:59', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
```